# C# - Download and Saving images to folder

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to  show a form that displays a label like "Updating, this window will close once update has finished" to download a few images files. I put this on my form's shown.

```
private void frmExtraUpdater_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            string _EmoticonURL = String.Format("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110636189/MapleEmoticons/f{0}.bmp", i);

            WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(_EmoticonURL);

            WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();

            Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream()); // Error

            webImage.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\Images\f" + i + ".bmp");
        }
    }
```

However.. once the form is shown, the label doesn't even show because it doesn't load it (It insantly downloades the images. I want it to show the label and only then start the download).

The other problem is that it throws "A generic error occurred in GDI+." on the webImgae.Save part for some reason.

Why's that?

Oh and.. if the folder "Images" does not exist, will it automatically create it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use `WebClient.DownloadFile` to save the file straight to disk? And no, the directory won't be created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Jon Skeet suggestion:

```
System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(String.Format("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110636189/MapleEmoticons/f{0}.bmp", i), Application.StartupPath + @"\Images\f" + i + ".bmp");
```

Use a background worker to update any UI components

```
BackgroundWorker backTask = new BackgroundWorker();
    public frmExtraUpdater()
    {
        backTask.DoWork += backTask_DoWork;
        backTask.RunWorkerCompleted += backTask_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }
    private void frmExtraUpdater_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourLabel.Text = "Downloading";
        backTask.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backTask_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile(String.Format("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110636189/MapleEmoticons/f{0}.bmp", i), Application.StartupPath + @"\Images\f" + i + ".bmp");
            backTask.ReportProgress(i * (100 / 8), String.Format("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110636189/MapleEmoticons/f{0}.bmp", i));
        }
    }

    void backTask_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        yourLabel.Text = "Downloading" + e.UserState.ToString();
    }

    void backTask_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the label issue? The label seems to be all white background and not showing and download starts straight away.

Comment: For some reason it says "An exception occurred during a WebClient request.". My saving/download URLs are fine. I tryied to put Thread.Sleep(3000) between each download but it's still failing.

Comment: Check your exception:  It may be proxy authentication requirement, ACL on your download directory, web site authentication

Answer (score 0):

You should use an async method, with webrequest async api (if you work with .net 4.5 or sup) or download your images in a background thread to avoid ui thread blocking.

You can try that:

```
    private void frmExtraUpdater_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (o, d) =>
        {
            saveImages();
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, f) =>
        {
            this.Close();
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void saveImages()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            string _EmoticonURL = String.Format("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110636189/MapleEmoticons/f{0}.bmp", i);

            WebRequest requestPic = WebRequest.Create(_EmoticonURL);

            WebResponse responsePic = requestPic.GetResponse();

            Image webImage = Image.FromStream(responsePic.GetResponseStream()); // Error

            webImage.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\Images\f" + i + ".bmp");
        }
    }
```